# Import-Module -Name MyModule.psm1 from Azure Devops Release Pipeline at my banch

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I like to decople funktions from my pipeline script and wrote a module. So far so good.

Now I need to import that module at runtime from my current branch (not master).

```
Import-Module -Name   "$($ENV:AGENT_RELEASEDIRECTORY)\$($ENV:RELEASE_PRIMARYARTIFACTSOURCEALIAS)\scripts\MyModule.psm1" -Force
```

Output

```
2021-09-06T18:07:41.8185223Z VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'D:\a\r1\a\_acr\scripts\MyModule.psm1'.
2021-09-06T18:07:42.0458821Z ##[error]Windows PowerShell is in NonInteractive mode. Read and Prompt functionality is not available.
2021-09-06T18:07:42.1872487Z ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure DevOps pipeline, the PowerShell session is in a non-interactive mode, which means if you define some user interactive needed functions and invoke them in your `MyModule.psm1`, it will cause the error.

So to import it successfully, make sure the functions don't need user interaction, if your requirement needs user interaction in Azure DevOps pipeline, I'm afraid you could not do that as it is not supported.

Comment: I do have some `CmdletBinding` in numerous functions inside that module, but the way I execute them is with the -confirm:$false argument. I've removed them and ignore the `PSShouldProcess` rule in `PSScriptAnalyzer`. Works fine now. Thanks!